# check induvial in multiple groups

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to know if a person exists in multiple groups. I have a dataframe in panda and it has the following data of almost 6k reviwerIds. I want to know that what is the overlap of people who are in group 1.0 price and also are in 4.0 price. I want to see the overlap.
what could be the best way to find that and also visualize it .

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: please supply a sample dataframe code `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` and an expected result